# Overwriting HTMLElement.classList property

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to override the HTMLElement.classList property in WebKit (Chrome) ?

I am trying with the following code:

```
    Object.defineProperty(window.HTMLElement.prototype, "classList", {
        get : function() { 
            console.log("test");
            return 1; 
        },  
        set : function(newValue){  },  
        enumerable : true,  
        configurable : true}
    );
```

However, calling `classList` of a DIV would still return the DOMTokenList.

Comment: I don't know if you're creating the div dynamically, but if so, you can overwrite `document.createElement` and define `classList` on the created element before returning the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should do what you've done with `HTMLDivElement`, not `HTMLElement`. However, I did that and still no result.

But if you want to do your job for the moment, you can apply your code directly on the `div` instance itself:

```
<div id='target' class='first second third'>
</div>
```

and:

```
var div = document.getElementById('target');
Object.defineProperty(div, 'classList', {
    get: function(){
        return 'overridden';
    }
});
alert(div.classList);
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/wn6R7/).

Answer (score 3):

Your div is not getting the `classList` from the prototype.  It is a direct property of the div.  The prototype chain is never searched:

```
myDiv.hasOwnProperty("classList"); // returns true
```

Comment: So, would there be a way to override the getter if I know the concrete object?

Comment: You would have to do it one at a time, on the individual elements you are targeting.  `Object.defineProperty(myDiv, "classList", ...`